# Increase or reducing server time by an hour

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

What should be: when you click on + the time on the screen should increase the hour. When you click on - the time on the screen should decrease by an hour.

What now: only real time on ajax(

How to transfer data and use Ajax to process it on the server?

I have some considerations that I can not put together:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>


<form action="datetime.php" method="post">
    <div id="timer"></div>

    <button id="plus">+</button>
    <button id="minus">-</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        function update() {
          $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'datetime.php',
           dataType: 'json',
           timeout: 1000,
           success: function(data) {
              $("#timer").html(data); 
              window.setTimeout(update, 1000);
           }
          });
        }
        update();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

datetime.php

```
<?php 
    $msg     = date('d/m/Y h:i:s');
    $msgPlus  = date('d/m/Y h:i:s', strtotime("+1 hour"));
    $msgMinus = date('d/m/Y h:i:s', strtotime("-1 hour"));

    echo json_encode($msg);

    // echo json_encode($msg);
    // echo json_encode($msgPlus);
    // echo json_encode($msgMinus);
    //$counter = $_POST['counter'] ?? 0;
    //echo date('d/m/Y h:i:s', time() + (int)$counter * 3600);


    //    switch($_POST['znachenie']) {
    //  case "-": 
    //      $_SESSION['time_sdvig'] -= 3600; 
    //      $time = time()-$_SESSION['time_sdvig']; 
    //      $msg = date(date('d/m/Y h:i:s', $time); 
    //          break;
    //     case "+": 
    //      $_SESSION['time_sdvig'] += 3600; 
    //      $time = time()+3600; 
    //      $msg = date(date('d/m/Y h:i:s', $time); 
    //          break;
    //     case "none": 
    //      $msg = date(date('d/m/Y h:i:s', $_SESSION['time_sdvig']);
    //          break;
    // }
    //    echo $msg;
?>
```

Please help me, I'm very interested how to do it.

Comment: why would you want to use AJAX to change the displayed time? Also, you've made no attempt at all, SO requires you to make some attempt, because it is not a code writing service

Comment: it's not really clear what you try to do and where the problem is. Is it the 'how to add an hour' in js? Is it the 'how to send a dateTime to the server'? And after all: why include the server into that anyway? Sounds a bit like a XY Problem.

Comment: there are some syntax errors (missing `)`)  in your (commented) php btw.

Comment: finally: in php you're not taking any value of the ajax call, instead looking for a 'counter' and ''znachenie'. So speaking for me, I can't understand what you wanna do.

Comment: I need to increase the server time per hour, because I take the time from the server. I do not know how to associate + with the increase in server time per hour.

Comment: why not simply display/write to a js var the 'server time' when loading the html? `<?php echo date('your format'); ?>` - Then manipulate in javascript. No need for an ajax call every second.

Comment: Becouse server time should be updated in real time without reloading the page

Comment: the server time won't change every second (compared to the users time), but if you call the server every second to check the time you'll get a delay anyway.

Comment: my recommendation is to get the current offset (timezone) from the server _once_, then do what ever you need in the browser. Checkout [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)